# How to change the replicate_*_table variable without modifying my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, replication

what is the syntax of replicate_*_table without having to modify my.cnf file?
and do i need to restart mysqld for changes to be applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `replicate-do|ignore-db|table` variables cannot be set dynamically. In fact, they're a bit weird, since they're not even presented in `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` output.

So you have to specify these params in the `my.cnf` file.

Just as final note, regardless of these particular params, whenever you set a global variables dynamically (e.g. `SET GLOBAL sql_mode := 'TRADITIONAL'`) and then restart the mysqld server -- your changes are lost. Whenever the server starts up, it's what's written in the config file that takes place. No persistence for online changes.